# Stinespring's theorem: can we choose the dilation to be an isometry?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, complete-positivity

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\varphi: A \to B(H)$ be a completely positive contractive map. Stinespring's theorem says that there exists a $*$-representation $\pi: A \to B(H')$ and a bounded operator $V \in B(H,H')$ such that
$$\varphi(a) = V^*\pi(a)V$$
for all $a \in A$. Moreover, if $\varphi$ is unital, then $\pi$ can be chosen to be unital, in which case we see that $V^*V = 1$, i.e. $V$ is an isometry.

Assume $A$ to be non-unital. We obtain a unital completely positive map
$$\widetilde{\varphi}: \widetilde{A}\to B(H): a + \lambda 1 \mapsto \varphi(a)+ \lambda \operatorname{id}_H$$ (see '$C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations' by Brown-Ozawa, section 2.1)
so we can apply the unital case and obtain a unital $*$-representation $\kappa: \widetilde{A} \to B(H')$ and an isometry $V$ such that
$$\varphi(a)+ \lambda \operatorname{id}_H = V^* \kappa(a+ \lambda 1) V$$
for all $a \in A$ and all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. However, taking $\lambda = 0$  yields
$$\varphi(a) = V^* \kappa(a)V$$
for all $a \in A$ so we can always choose $V$ to be an isometry in the Stinespring decomposition if $A$ is non-unital (and $\varphi$ is c.c.p).

Is this correct? If not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's correct, but $\kappa|_A$ is degenerate, unless $\varphi(e_i)\to1$ in SOT for an approximate unit $(e_i)_i$.

Comment: Based on your other questions, it seems that you are reading Takesaki's first volume on operator algebras, theorem 3.6 and remark 3.7 in Chapter IV of his book also treats this question from a slightly different perspective.